# Add different values to each matrix in a list

Tags: r, list, replace

Can't get my head wraped around this problem. I know how to do it the dirty -`for-loop`-way, but I am sure there is some elegant base-R or `purrr` approach.

I have a list of n matrices that are the same:

```r
a <- matrix(ceiling(rnorm(4)), nrow = 2)
l <- list(mget(rep("a", 3)))        
l
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$a
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    2    2
#> [2,]    0    0
#> 
#> [[1]]$a
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    2    2
#> [2,]    0    0
#> 
#> [[1]]$a
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    2    2
#> [2,]    0    0

x <- 1:3
```

Now I want to replace in each matrix `i`, say, the `[1,2]` element by the `i`'th value in `x`.

How do I do that?

Comment: I'm still trying to wrap my head around why you are doing this, although base R allows you to do it...

Comment: I am doing Monte Carlo simulations. I need to create different data generating processes based on a correlation matrix. The different DGP's contain minor changes to one element. This is why i need to have the same matrix n times and modify each matrix according to some values in a vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map`

```
Map(function(x,y) replace(x, 3, y), l, x)
```

Or

```
Map(function(x,y) {x[1,2] <- y; x}, l, x)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
a <- matrix(ceiling(rnorm(4)), nrow = 2)
l <- mget(rep("a", 3))
```